# Elements on same line in bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to get 2 elements on same line within a bootstrap column because I don't want a gap that putting it in a separate col would create.

```
<style>
   .inline {
             display: inline-block;
           }
</style>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="inline">View</label>
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.View, new {@class = "form-control inline"})
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SportId, Model.Sports, new {@class = "form-control"})
            </div>
</div>
```

Output is like this:
[image]

Edit: I think many of you misunderstood what I need. Iswarya got me on the right track. Just had to created another col within the col like this:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">               
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>View</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.View, new {@class = "form-control"})
                </div>                
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SportId, Model.Sports, new {@class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which created:
[image]

Comment: How does it look like when you add `<label class="inline"></label>` directly above the second combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here is the code for your question and use bootstrap and it saves your day .

```
<form  class="form-horizontal" id="form1 " >
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-6">customer Name<span class="impstar">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" Placeholder="Enter Name" re>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-6">pounds<span class="impstar">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" Placeholder="Ex : 20" >
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-6">us dollars<span class="impstar">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" Placeholder="Ex : Rs.60,000" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-6">euro dollars<span class="impstar">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" Placeholder="Ex : Rs.35,000" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group text-right">

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit ">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: ah, adding another col-md-x div within the existing one did the trick!

Comment: hoo thats fine enjoy your day buddy @BMills

Answer (score 0):

You may also swap .row for .form-row, a variation of our standard grid row that overrides the default column gutters for tighter and more compact layouts.

**[Form row](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)**

**Try like this**

```
<form>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="View>View</label>
          @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.View, new {@class = "form-control "})
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="lable-text"></label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SportId, Model.Sports, new {@class = "form-control"})
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is

`<label>view>/label>` on right hand and for next field there is no label that's why its getting misaligned.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SportId, Model.Sports, new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

for this div write following css

`vertical-align: middle or bottom or sub`

Comment: I think you misundersttod the question. I want the label 'View' and the associated dropdown on the same line

Answer (score 0):

if you using bootstap 4 then just add `mt-auto` in div.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
   .inline {
             display: inline-block;
           }
</style>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="">View</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mt-auto">
                <select class="form-control">
                </select>
            </div>
</div>
```